# Is there a way to organize the source tree in Eclipse Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not an expert in Java Eclipse development but have created a few projects in it. In the past the source tree was pretty small maybe less than 10 source files, but this is the first time with a large source tree. The number of source files is probably 30+ and it takes forever to open and find a source files from the gigantic list.

Is there a way to organize the source folder within Eclipse logically without affecting the source paths or Eclipse ability to compile and parse them? Like logical "group folders" those found in the Xcode IDE or Visual Studio?

Comment: ctrl+shift+r start typing file name.

Comment: Well, 30 is not too much. Anyways, aren't your source files under relevant packages?

Comment: I think that 'ctrl+shift+t'is more suitable since it helps you to find classes/interfaces/enums. 'ctrl+shift+r'will help you to find any type of file in the workspace

Answer (score 3):

If you have lots of files, you should be organizing them into packages (and even separate modules/projects if possible to help keep your code clean).  This will require moving them into new directories, but that's part of how Java works, and moving classes between packages is a common task that Eclipse will handle easily; if you drag-and-drop a class from one package to another, Eclipse will update the necessary references in all the open projects in your workspace.

Answer (score 3):

In order to organize the source folder logically, you can use Working Sets. By doing this, you do not need to change the structure of your project. It is possible to assign projects, packages or single resources to working sets. See for example 
http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2005/06/19/organizing-eclipse-projects-with-working-sets/